# What does `ParseTreeListener` mean in ANTLR?

Tags: antlr, antlr4, antlr3

I read the following statement about `ParseTreeListener` from the book *< The Definitive ANTLR 4 Reference >*:

> ANTLR generates a ParseTreeListener subclass specific to ***each grammar***
>   with enter and exit methods for each rule.

I am a bit confused about the `each grammar` notion. My undertanding is:

- A language is equivalent to its grammar.
- A grammar is just a set of rules.
- A program is equivalent to a parse tree representing it.

So if we are working on a language application with ANTLR, there should be only one grammar. Thus there should be only one `ParseTreeListener`. So what does the `each` mean here?

### ADD 1

As I read on, I have a feeling that the `grammar` here is *merely* specific to a `*.g4` file. And maybe a language can have multiple `*.g4` files. I am not sure if I am correct on this. I will keep updating this question.

Comment: You can have a language application with multiple languages, like island-languages, which are described in the same book.

Comment: @Mephy Is it possible for a single language to be defined in multiple *.g4 grammar files? Maybe I haven't read it yet.

Comment: @smwikipedia Often you split up the declarations of lexer rules and parser rules in two different files. Another option is to use an import (which loads a set of rules from a file).

Answer (score 2):

after you define a .g4 grammar you can tell Antlr4 to generate a class that implements ParseTreeListener. In more detail, say you have a grammar `Lang` then Antlr4 generates an interface `LangParserListener` and a class `LangParserBaseListener`.

- The interface defines all the enter- and exit-methods as mentioned above.
- The class `LangParserBaseListener` gives you a default 'no-operation' implementation for each of the methods (note that there are two methods for each expression in Lang.g4 - so this could be a pretty large class/interface).

The main point of `LangParserBaseListener` is that it makes it easier to add a listener that only wants to 'listen' a small subset of the rules. For that simply inherit from it and override the respective methods.

And it does make perfectly sense to implement multiple listeners per grammar, e.g. a first pass to define all occurring symbols and a second pass to de-reference all symbolic references. This is also part of the reference textbook on Antlr4.

hope that helps
fricke